# Checkout An Angular SVN Project Into Atom Editor

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, atom-editor

I am trying to checkout an Angular Project from a remote SVN Repository into my Atom editor.

I installed tortoise-svn package into my Atom editor.
But I am unable to find SNV checkout option in my Atom editor as shown below,

[image]

I also tried to install TortoiseSVN in my system and created a folder ,when i rightclick on the folder it gives me the SVN Checkout option as shown below

[image]

can anybody please guide me through how can I checkout my angular application from the SVN repository directly into my workspace(Atom Editor)

Comment: can anybody please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From TortoiseSVN you simply right click on the folder you want to check out to:

1. SVN Checkout...
2. Type in the URL of the repository (https://www.example.com/repos/MyRepo/trunk)
3. Everything else on the screen should be what you need (HEAD revision, fully recursive and if you right clicked on the folder, Checkout directory should be auto-populated, but you can modify it as need be).

And then all you have to do is hit **OK**.

Comment: yes i know this procedure ,but i want to take the application directly in to my workspace rather than creating a folder and then performing check out.

Comment: i want to know is there any option in Atom Editor for checkout with tortoise SVN?

Comment: @Heena ask Atom Editor developers.